# jQuery - plugin not working with custom scrollbar

Tags: jquery

http://grabbers.maddoggmedia.com/

Using the malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin for the #chat-box-chats id but not seeming to work. It works perfectly here....

http://grabbers.maddoggmedia.com/chat.html

When you click on the text input it opens up, need the custom scrollbar plugin to work but cant seem to figure it out. I'm sure it something simple as it works fine on other pages.

```
<script type="text/javascript">(function($){
    $(window).load(function(){
        $("#chat-box-chats,chat-box-message").mCustomScrollbar();
    });
})(jQuery);</script>
```

Would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Can someone please help me with this?!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing class notation `'.'` here:

```
$("#chat-box-chats,.chat-box-message").mCustomScrollbar();
//-----------------^--------------------------------------here this missing '.'
```

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">(function($){
    $(window).load(function(){
        $("#chat-box-chats").mCustomScrollbar();
    });
})(jQuery);</script>

Comment: still not working for some reason. It works fine on the other pages

Answer (score 0):

you can try calling the scrollbar on the required element on click event .. i.e when a user clicks on a chat window.. and after the chatbox div has been displayed..
As most  most of these scroller plugins don't work on hidden elements..